# Get node value in XML using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I'm trying to parse the following XML:

```
<AssetImageModel xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ErgonFileService.Model" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <AssetId>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</AssetId>
    <AssetImageId>b74af53a-91e6-83f5-26f9-e1719ad5fd05</AssetImageId>
    <ImagePath i:nil="true"/>
    <IsDeleted>false</IsDeleted>
    <Modified>false</Modified>
    <Version>0</Version>
</AssetImageModel>
```

In order to retrieve for example the `AssetImageId` value. What would be the easiest way to achieve this using either JS or jQuery?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are having a xml text then use $.parseXML() to parse it to a xml object then use find() to locate the element.

```
var text = '<AssetImageModel xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ErgonFileService.Model" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><AssetId>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</AssetId><AssetImageId>b74af53a-91e6-83f5-26f9-e1719ad5fd05</AssetImageId><ImagePath i:nil="true"/><IsDeleted>false</IsDeleted><Modified>false</Modified><Version>0</Version></AssetImageModel>'

var xml = $.parseXML(text);
console.log($(xml).find('AssetImageId').text())
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/x3Uuz/)

If you are using ajax then set the `dataType: 'xml'` so that you can get the parsed object as the data in your success handler

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/9w8JN/)